# Changing the Pod and Service CIDR?

Tags: container, kubernetes, microk8s

How would one go about changing the:

- Pod (10.1.0.0/16)
- Service (10.152.183.0/24)
- - Kubernetes API (10.152.183.1)
- - CoreDNS (10.152.183.10)

CIDRs that come stock with installing Microk8s?
I run a 10.0.0.0/8 internally and would prefer switching to another private range for these.

There is reference to the Pod CIDR here (https://microk8s.io/docs/change-cidr)

TIA